# Why is a deck transformation completely determined by where it sends a single point?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Hatcher says "by the unique lifting property, a deck transformation is [completely determined by where it sends a single point](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf#page=79#), assuming $\tilde{X}$ is path-connected".

But I have no idea how this unique lifting property should be used. Could anyone show me what he means here?

Comment: Just check that if $p\colon \tilde X\to X$ is a covering map, then any deck transformation is a lift of $p$.

Comment: and in the connected case, like you are, a lift is uniquely determined by a choice of a point

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tilde x_1$ be point in $\tilde X$. Let $\tilde \gamma$ be path in $\tilde X$ from $\tilde x_0$ to $\tilde x_1$. Let $\gamma$ be $p_1 \circ \tilde \gamma$.  Let $\tilde \gamma ' $ be lift of $\gamma$ in $p_2$ with starting point $f(\tilde x_0) $. This lift is unique by ULP. Thus $f(\tilde x_1)$ is fixed as end point of this lift.